# Rails4 route not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a route like this.

```
 get 'mypage' => 'mypage#browserUpdate'
```

I added a controller called:

mypage_controller.rb

```
class MypageController < ApplicationController

  def browserUpdate
    puts "browser_update controller working"
  end


end
```

In my views folder I have a folder called.
mypage > browserUpdate.html.erb

When i put a link in the application.html.erb

```
<div><%= link_to 'UPGRADE PATH', mypage_path %></div>
```

When I click the link I get an error:

> Assertion failed: The URL '/mypage' did not match any routes in your
>   application

Rake routes says. `mypage GET /mypage(.:format) mypage#browserUpdate`

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: have you done rake routes?

Comment: Rake routes says.  mypage GET      /mypage(.:format)                               mypage#browserUpdate

Comment: Looks like things should work. Do you have cache classes enabled?  Will need a server restart if you have that enabled in development.

Comment: I did a rails s to restart the server but still getting the same error.

Comment: What happens when you directly access the page?

Comment: http://0.0.0.0:3000/mypage/browserUpdate No route matches [GET] "/mypage/browserUpdate

Answer (score 0):

I think your controller should be plural, i.e. it should be mypagescontroller.

Comment: You mean the name of it or what's inside the file? Never had to do that before ?

Answer (score 0):

routes.rb

```
get 'mypage' => 'mypage#browserUpdate', as: 'browser_update'
```

application.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'UPGRADE PATH', browser_update_path %>
```

This should help.